# How to set server specific variables on a discord bot?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I'm creating a discord bot using node.js. I need help making server specific variables (that cant be used on other servers or could be differnet)

I searched for something and the only result was to track my variables by guild id. The problem is it uses 'message.guild.id' so that means i can't use it before checking for messages.

This is how the code to setting the prefix should look:

```
function setPrefix(message, arguments){
    prefix[message.guild.id] = arguments
}
```

And this is how I wanted to set it at the start of the code:

```
prefix = {}
prefix[guild.id] = "@"
```

I tried it, but, of course, i can't get the guild id like that so it would be undefined every time i tried. What could I do? (please note im not very experienced)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the list of all the guilds your bot is a member of in [`<Client>.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds). You just need to iterate over them and set the prefix you want.

Quick snippet to set the prefix for every guild Id the bot is in to "@":

```
var Discord = require("discord.js");

var client = new Discord.Client();

var prefix = {};
var defaultPrefix = "@";

client.on("ready", function(){
    var allGuilds = client.guilds;
    //initialize all prefixes to a default prefix
    allGuilds.tap(function(guild){
        prefix[guild.id] = defaultPrefix;
    });
});

client.login("BOT_TOKEN")
```